# first module, hook_menu/FAPI problem

Tags: 7, routes

I'm fairly new to Drupal and made my first module. It works. Yay!

*What I have*: Calling
`/form-test/186` (nid)
Nid gets loaded, renders content.

*What I want*: The same but with an simple submit button at the end, that calls a

```
function exportIt() {
  // put $output from formtest_page() in email
}
```

when clicked, not before.

```
    <?php


/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function formtest_menu() {
  $items['form-test/%'] = array(
  'title' => 'Export von:',
  'page callback' => 'formtest_page',
  //'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array(1),
  //'page arguments' => array(formtest_simple_form),
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK, );
  return $items;
}

function formtest_page($nid = NULL) {

  $node = node_load($nid);
  if ($node) {
    $title = $node -> title;
    dpm($node); //Why is this not get displayed?
    drupal_set_title('Klicket Export von: ' . $title);
    $output = '';
    $items = array("<b>titel: </b>" . $title,
    "Where is my beef?" );

    $output .= theme('item_list', array('items' => $items));
    //drupal_get_form('formtest_simple_form');
    return $output;

  }
  return;
}

function exportIt() {
  // put $output from formtest_page() in email
}

//simple submit form
function formtest_simple_form($form, &$form_submit) {
$form['submit'] = array(
'#type' => 'submit',
'#value' => t('Export an Klicket'));
return $form;
}
```

I'm having basic conceptional issues I guess. I either can render the submit Button or the Output, but not both.

Comment: This site prefers if you inline your code so please do so. Also, please don't use pastebin.com. There are tons of clean pastebins like  http://paste.pocoo.org, http://pastebin.ca,  http://pastebin.org, http://pastie.textmate.org http://codr.cc and http://codepad.org/ .

Comment: I looked into the form examples module. But the just render forms, not both...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code is similar to the following one.

I will add some notes about the code as I wrote it:

- If you use "form-test/%node" (instead "form-test/%"), the node will be loaded from Drupal, and if there are some problems with loading it, it will report an error (404, page not found) to the user; in this way, you don't need to call `node_load()` as that is already done by Drupal.
- There is a callback that returns the title Drupal should use.
- I am not sure I translated correctly the strings you were using (I guess it was Swedish, but I am not positive, as I don't know Swedish); I had to translate the strings, as `t()`'s argument is a string in English, which will be translated in the language set for the site.

```
function formtest_menu() {
  $items['form-test/%node'] = array(
    'title' => 'Export',
    'title callback' => 'formtest_title',
    'title arguments' => array(1),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array(formtest_simple_form, 1),
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}

function formtest_title($node) {
  return t('Export Klicket from @title', array('@title' => $node->title));
}

function formtest_simple_form($form, &$form_state, $node) {
  $form['#node'] = $node;

  $items = array(
    t("<strong>Title: @title</strong>", array('@title' => $node->title)),
    t("Where is my beef?")
  );

  $form['item_list'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'item_list',
    '#items' => $items,
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Export as Klicket')
  );

  return $form;
}

function formtest_simple_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
   // Write the email.
   // If you need the node object, it is in $form['#node'].
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I do not get what your problem is but usually what you do is, set `page callback` to `drupal_get_form` , `page arguments => array('my_form_id');` then instead of naming it exportIt you name it `my_form_id_submit`.

Comment: But where will my `function formtest_page()` go? I have to display my `$node` content first. So my page arguments has to be `'page arguments' => array(1)`

Comment: `$form['whatever'] = array('#theme' => 'item_list', '#items' => $items);` a form can contain anything not just input elements.